# Organizing files in a SBT-based scala project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Newcomer to the Intellij IDE here, with no Java background. I've looked at [Build Definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html) to get a brief idea on how should I organize my scala files, but their example doesn't cover the full structure of an SBT-based project shown attached.

Can you advise what each folder should be used for (e.g. where my source files should go, etc.) and also point me to sources where I can go read up more.

Thanks so much
[image: Project structure]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is described pretty well here:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Directories.html

But to sum up.

**.idea:**
This contains the project files for your idea project, and has nothing directly to do with sbt itself. However idea (if auto refresh is enabled) updates its own project, each time the sbt build files change.

**project:**
This contains the sbt project files, except for the main build file (files ending in `.sbt`). Sbt build is itself based on scala, and if you need to have some scala code included in your build (e.g., code-generation/meta-programming, pre-compiler macros), then you can place scala source files in this directory. The code of these files can be used in your build system, and is not part of your project itself. To really understand how a build is made, then you will need to understand the difference in how sbt files and scala files for the build should be placed. When you run sbt, then it will search for `.sbt` files in the directory your are standing in, when these are found, it will search for scala files in the project directory. These files together are the source of the build system, but because these are source files, they need to be built before they can be used. To build this build system, sbt uses sbt. So a build system to build the build system is needed. It therefore looks for sbt files inside the project directory, and scala files for this build inside project/project and build these files to get a build system, that can build the build system (that can build your project). Actually it can continue recursive down to any `project/project/project...` directory, until it finds a project folder containing no scala files, and therefore needs no building before use.

The target folder inside project, is the target folder for the sbt build of your build definition. See below what a target folder is.

Normally you would not need to be concerned about this; just remember that `build.sbt` in your root directory is the build script for your project. `project/plugins.sbt` defines plugins activated for your build system, and `project/build.properties` contains special sbt properties. Currently the only sbt property I now of, is what version of sbt should be used.

**src:**
This is where your place the source files of your project. You should place any java sources in `src/main/java`, scala sources in `src/main/scala`. Resources are placed in `src/main/resources`.

The `src/main/scala_2.11` folder is typically used, if you have some code that it not binary compatible with different versions of scala. In such cases you would be able to configure sbt to use different source files when building for different versions of scala. You probably do not need this, so I would advise to just delete the `src/main/scala_2.11` folder.

Test sources are placed inside `src/test/java` and `source/test/scala`, and test resources are placed in `src/test/resources`.

**target**
This folder is the target folder for sbt. All compiled files, generated packages and so on are placed somewhere inside this dir.

Most things in this dir are not so interesting, as most of it is just internal sbt things. However if your build a jar file by calling `sbt package`, then it will be placed inside `target/scala-x` (where `x` is the scala version). There are also a lot of different plugins, that can package your application in different ways, and they will normally also place the package files somewhere inside the target dir.

Comment: Could you please suggest changes required in build.sbt as mentioned in below problem. I am new to SBT world and facing exactly same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070814/data-proc-job-is-failing-with-class-not-found-exception