# Cannot access project-wide dependencies in source-generator files

Tags: scala, import, sbt

I have a play framework application with a directory structure like this:

```
server
  - app
    - services
      - MyService.scala
  - project
    - Dependencies.scala
    - src/main/scala
      - MyMetaService.scala
  - build.sbt
```

The `/project` directory hosts a source code generator task (sbt Task) for which I'd like to be able to use Circe. My `build.sbt` file *does* include reference to the circe package and if I issue:

```scala
import io.circe._
```

in `MyService.scala` the package resolves fine. But if I do the *same* in `MyMetaService.scala` the package does not resolve. I know this is because somehow I'm not specifying that the dependency should apply to the `/project` directory but I don't know how to do that. Here's my `build.sbt`:

```
import src.main.scala.generate.ModelGenerator

name := "server"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `server` =
  (project in file("."))
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.dependencies)
    .enablePlugins(PlayScala)

resolvers ++=
  Seq(
    "Akka Snapshot Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/",
    "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
    "releases" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases",
    "snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
  )

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

sourceGenerators in Compile ++= Seq(
  ModelGenerator.generatorTask.taskValue
)
```

And my `Dependencies.scala`:

```
import play.sbt.PlayImport._
import sbt._

object Dependencies {

  val dependencies: Seq[ModuleID] =
    Seq(
      jdbc,
      ehcache,
      ws,
      specs2 % Test,
      guice,
      "io.circe" %% "circe-core" % "0.11.1",
      "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.11.1",
      "io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % "0.11.1"
    )

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create separate `build.sbt` for meta-build project in `project/build.sbt` and import dependencies in the same way as for proper build. For example

```
// This is project/build.sbt

val circeVersion = "0.10.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.circe" %% "circe-core",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-generic",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-parser"
).map(_ % circeVersion)
```

should now make circe available to `project/.../MyMetaService.scala`

Comment: If I do this, does it make sense for me also to have a `/project/Dependencies.scala` file?

Comment: Sure, just `import Dependencies._` at the top of `project/build.sbt` in the same way as for the proper build.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting object `Dependencies` not found. The IDE recognizes it, but sbt is complaining.

Comment: `Dependencies.scala` for the meta-build needs to go into `project/project/Dependencies.scala` (yes that is indeed two levels `project/project`) to be accessible from `project/builds.sbt`. SBT build structure is recursive. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39611169/5205022).

Comment: Right. I figured that out. But doesn't that mean I will need to have two sets of `Dependencies.scala`? One for the project and one for the meta-project. I guess there isn't a way to unify shared dependencies across projects?