# Data proc job is failing with Class not found exception

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform, sbt

I just started learning GCP and IntelliJ SBT for the first time.Please bear with me for any basic question.

My project structure:

[image: Project and SBT Build structure]

Here is my SBT.Build

name := "MySBTproject"

```
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
val moutlingyaml = "net.jcazevedo" %% "moultingyaml" % "0.4.2"
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "MySBTproject",
    libraryDependencies += moutlingyaml
  )
```

Then i ran SBT package from Terminal to create a jar as shown below

```
C:\Users\xyz\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject>SBT Package
```

After deploying this jar on to GCP bucket,i tried running the job using data proc

```
  gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
--cluster my-cluster \
--region europe-north1  \
--jars gs://test-my-bucket-01/spark-jobs/mysbtproject_2.11-0.1.jar \
--class com.test.processing.jobs.mytestmain
```

I am getting below error once i run the job

```
Job failed with message [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.processing.jobs.mytestmain]
```

Is it because of my custom project directory structure and build.sbt are not in sync?

Are any changes required, or do i need to create a jar from project sub-directory as shown below?

```
C:\Users\xyz\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\ProcessDataDataProcessingJobs>SBT Package
```

Comment: A little correction in the last commandC:\Users\xyz\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\ProcessData\DataProcessingJobs>SBT Package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` directory should be in directory pointed by `project.in(directory)`. In your case project directory is `ProcessData`, while your `src` is in `ProcessData/DataProcessingJobs`. So I'm guessing that sbt doesn't see your code at all, doesn't compile it, and doesn't package it.

You can check it by opening JAR (after all it's just a ZIP file with classes in directories!) and by calling `show sourceDirectories` to see where sbt is looking for you code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Since we are new to SBT,could you please suggest the  changes that needs to be done in my SBT.build . Would be greatful if you can provide the details

Comment: Simply match (sub)project's directory with the directory that contains `src` - so either move src one directory up or set project to `project.in("DataProcessingJobs")`.

Comment: val moutlingyaml = "net.jcazevedo" %% "moultingyaml" % "0.4.2"
lazy val root = (project in file("DataProcessingJobs"))
  .settings(
    name := "DataProcessingJobs",
    version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
    libraryDependencies += moutlingyaml
  )

Comment: We have done the suggested changes.But still getting the same error.

Comment: You haven't written if you checked if your code is in the JAR nor what are the sourceDirectories

Comment: I have accepted your answer.But could  you please see my response below and provide more details to resolve the issue. I am novice to sbt ,so your inputs would be helpful in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since i do not have privilege to edit the question i am attaching the details as an answer.Once i get the proper answer i will delete my answer.

Below is the error i am getting when i am running from "run" on the IntelliJ window panel
[image]

Also i have verified the Jar file and found that no classes were there,And below is the contnets of jar and manifest file.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: MySBTproject
Implementation-Version: 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
Specification-Vendor: default
Specification-Title: MySBTproject
Implementation-Vendor-Id: default
Specification-Version: 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
Implementation-Vendor: default
```

and JAR file contents are in below image
[image]

request you to advise on what further needs to be done.

When i ran show directories command in sbt shell below are the outputs

```
MySBTproject> show sourceDirectories
    [info] root / Compile / sourceDirectories
    [info]  List(C:\Users\XXXXX\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\DataProcessingjobs\src\main\scala-2.11, C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\DataProcessingjobs\src\main\scala, C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\DataProcessingjobs\src\main\java, C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\DataProcessingjobs\target\scala-2.11\src_managed\main)
    [info] Compile / sourceDirectories
    [info]  List(C:\Users\XXXXXX\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\src\scala-2.12, C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\src\scala, C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\src\java, C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\target\scala-2.12\src_managed\main
    
    [info]  List(C:\Users\XXXXXX\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\src\scala-2.12, C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\src\scala, C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\src\java, C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\IdeaProjects\MySBTproject\target\scala-2.12\src_managed\main)
    [IJ]sbt:MySBTproject>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently received the same error when executing a jar on Google Cloud DataProc.  I'm not sure if this is the same issue you are having, but please give it a try if you are still having this issue and have not resolved it.

My setup is:

- Scala 2.11.12
- sbt 1.3.13
- Spark SQL 2.3.2

For me, the issue was related to the removal of the system property `io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolverProvider.enable_grpclb` in `grpc v1.29.0`.  You can read more about it at the **googleapis/java-logging** [issue on github](https://github.com/googleapis/java-logging/issues/276) from Oct 8, 2020. Look for the comment by user **athakor**.

The resolution was to add the dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-logging" % "1.102.0" exclude("io.grpc", "grpc-alts")

libraryDependencies += "io.grpc" % "grpc-alts" % "1.29.0"
```